# Download direct download to specific folder

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-re

I have this code where I am using beautifulsoup to get a url for a direct download link to a pdf and save it into a specific directory.

Getting the url for the link works, it is just getting it to download and save in a directory that is causing problems. I have searched through several sources and finally  tried urllib.urlretrieve but this is not working.

Could I get assistance, please.
Edit: Main thing I am trying to do is to get the code to download the direct link and not having to manually click it.

If the url is needed for helping here it is; https://www.odfl.com/us/en/resources/tariffs/tariff-odfl-100-0.html
As I am parsing through an xml, as there are several other urls that require different code.

```
import sys
import os
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def ODFL100(tariff_id):

    try:

        pdf_path = ParseXML(tariff_id)
        r = requests.get(pdf_path,stream = True)
        download_path = ParseXML(tariff_id,1)

        link_list = []
        pdf_link = ""
        pdf_found = 0

        r = requests.get(pdf_path)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

        base = urlparse(pdf_path)
        for i in soup.find_all('a'):
            if pdf_found == 0:
                current_link = i.get('href')
            else:
                break
            if current_link.endswith('pdf'):
                link_list.append(base.scheme+"://"+base.netloc + current_link)
                for l in link_list:
                    pdf_link = l
                    if "rates-and-tariffs"  in pdf_link:
                        pdf_found = 1
        urllib.urlretrieve(pdf_link, download_path)

    except Exception as error:
        error_message = "A " + str(error)
```

Comment: Hi @K J, I get that you can get the download from just clicking the link. But I want to have the program do it as there are further steps I have it doing after. The main purpose is to avoid the manual action. Thanks though, but still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. But here is an example code that will download a pdf file from a specified page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.odfl.com/us/en/resources/tariffs/tariff-odfl-100-0.html'
response = requests.get(url)
link = 'https://www.odfl.com' + BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find('a', class_='cmp-form-button').get('href')
with open(requests.utils.unquote((link.split('/')[-1])), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, Thanks the open with piece does the downloading that I needed thank you. Another question; Is there a way to point it to another directory as it automatically saves to the downloads folder?

Comment: Got it Thanks @Sergey K, just needed to change up the with open() to my directory the last piece was the missing part. Thanks again.